# While trying to render a particle animation with a transparent background, render shows a black background

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine, transparency

When I click the transparency under film render properties it shows transparent in the viewport, but when I render an image it shows a black background instead of transparent.

Particles render fine and the animation I have also renders fine. The only problem I have is the background not being transparent in the render. I tried changing the output properties to   PNG format and RGBA and rendering as images, but it does not fix the problem.

Viewport:
[image: viewport]

Render:
[image]

I'm using Eevee renderer.

Here is my file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nqAhWD9VREQj-J9e9L7mawKdia61NRy0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: pls provide blend file because we cannot see any important settings you made. thx.

Comment: Hello are your sure that you don't have objects that are hidden for preview but enabled for render? check the Outliner...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to upload your file. However, the file is +300MB, it's HUGE for what - according to your screenshots - should only be particles in a vacuum, that's no more than 1MB tops. Even with an above average network, it takes almost a minute to download 300MB, I won't even guess how long it takes for other people. For next time, please read [How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice - Blender Meta Stack Exchange](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3051/53447) so to save yourself and others some time and frustrations ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's an object called *Limit* that is disabled for preview but enabled for render, disable it for render if you don't want it to mask the transparency. Also disable the *Output > Post Processing > Sequencer* option otherwise the movie in your *Video Sequencer* will be rendered instead of your scene. At last enable the *Render > Film > Transparent* option.

[image]